# How do I permission an AWS SQS to be read by only one lambda?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have tried to apply the following SQS Policy but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "SqsEdsPerms",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "20180503",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6000000000:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:SendMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:6000000000:scs-dev-use1-myQueue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": [
            "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:6000000000:function:scs-dev-use1-myLambda"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to write another lambda (myLambda2) and still read messages off the SQS (myQueue).

Comment: Does the IAM Role assigned to `myLambda2` have any SQS permissions?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "read only"? Normally, a process reads a message from an Amazon SQS queue via `ReceiveMessage`. If it successfully processes the message, it should then call `DeleteMessage`. Alternatively, if the Lambda function is setup to trigger from an Amazon SQS queue, then there is no need to assign SQS permissions because the message is provided directly to the Lambda function and deletion is handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The "Principal" is the resource which is being granted permissions, so the ARN of your lambda should go there.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "SqsEdsPerms",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "20180503",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:6000000000:function:scs-dev-use1-myLambda"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:SendMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:6000000000:scs-dev-use1-myQueue"
    }
  ]
}
```